# Move to start of storyboard from button on last screen

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm trying to get a storyboard to bring the user back to the first screen of a storyboard when a button is pressed.

I have the button click hooked up and the method is hit when it's tapped but it's either doing nothing or crashing the app depending on what I've got in that method (I've tried so many things at this stage that I can't remember the original setup)

The best I can achieve is that once tapped the user gets brought to the third screen in the storyboard, rather than the first.

Here's the storyboard, I want to get the user to move from the button circled in red back to the very first view controller (top left of screenshot).

Maybe the storyboard layout will help people, I'll post some of the various methods I've tried   as well.[image]

Here's the method

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
   //Multitude of attempts have been in here, either they don't do 
   //anything or they just send the user back to the NEW REPORT screen.
//Button does nothing in these following events

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 


[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you have tried this [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Yes tried that, when using that the button does nothing, just clicks with no effect.

Comment: Are you instantiating the report sending view controller's navigation controller in code?  There is no segue shown in your storyboard.

Comment: I think I am, in that view controller I've added UINavigationControllerDelegate to the @interface declaration.

Comment: Try this      [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

Comment: In that case, popping to root view controller does nothing because report sending view controller is the root view controller of its navigation controller.  In which view controller do you instantiate it?

Comment: @Anand K, yes tried that as well, same effect - nothing.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton In your program flow, what triggers the display of the report sending view controller?

Comment: Do you want to go back to the same instance of that first controller, or a new instance? Is the goal to start over fresh, or do you have things ion that first controller that you need to preserve?

Comment: @Steve, I instantiated it within the same view controller, so like you say it sounds 'correct' that it's doing nothing, how do I instantiate it from another view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar goal is to start afresh, don't want to keep anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start fresh, have the button instantiate a new instance of the first controller, and set it as the window's root view controller:

```
FirstViewController *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
self.view.window.rootViewController = first;
```

It's not clear to me exactly how you're getting to that controller with the button in question, but you might want to put dealloc methods in all your controllers with a log to see if all are getting deallocated at some point in your navigation, and when you go back to the new first controller as I've outlined above.

Comment: In my code where do I get the name to substitute the 'FirstViewController' with? I've tried with the name of the controller but it says unknown type.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton, you substitute the class of that controller -- whatever your custom class is. Also, make sure you give the controller an identifier.

Comment: Hmm...still saying unknown type name when I use the class, it has an identifier, should the identifier be the same name as the class?

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton, no, the identifier can be anything you want as long as you use the same one in the code. If that first controller is the default one you get with a single view project, then its class should be ViewController. You also need to import its .h file into the .m of that last controller.